# How to get a spawner that spawns experience bottles?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to set up an afk xp farm for my server. And I want XP bottles to spawn from a spawner.

I've tried this so far

```
/minecraft:give @s minecraft:spawner{BlockEntityTag:{Delay:1,MinSpawnDelay:1,MaxSpawnDelay:1,SpawnData:{id:"minecraft:experience_orb",Value:7},SpawnPotentials:[{Weight:1,Entity:{id:"minecraft:experience_bottle",Value:7}}]}}
```

It does give me a spawner, but nothing spawns.

Comment: Maybe you could use falling sand blocks?

Answer (score 1):

An answer to why the original command didn't work:

1. Catn't run the give command with `minecraft:` in front.
2. The `SpawnData` tag requires an entity, so instead of:

```
SpawnData:{id:"minecraft:experience_orb",Value:7}
```

You need this:

```
SpawnData:{entity:{id:"minecraft:experience_orb",Value:7}}
```

This will give a spawner that spawns experience orbs. If you change it to `experiance_bottle` it will drop bottles instead.

---

The last tag `SpawnPotentials` doesn't seem to have any effect on the spawner. Removing the entire tag doesn't change anything about the end product.

Edited command:

```
/give @s minecraft:spawner{BlockEntityTag:{Delay:1,MinSpawnDelay:1,MaxSpawnDelay:1,SpawnData:{entity:{id:"minecraft:experience_orb",Value:7}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a little testing in a creative world, and a little research and I found something that works.

This is the give command that spawned XP orbs consistently

```
/give @s spawner{BlockEntityTag:{SpawnCount:10,MinSpawnDelay:20,MaxSpawnDelay:60,MaxNearbyEntities:32,RequiredPlayerRange:8,SpawnData:{entity:{id:"minecraft:experience_orb",Value:16}}}} 1
```

I am baffled as to why your command doesn't work. If anyone knows why, please comment on the question/answer for future readers.